# UITableView Group Headings Disappear With ContentInset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm attempting to have a UITableView header snap to a closer and open state and have achieved the functionality by setting the contentInset; the issue with this solution seems to be that my group headings also have the inset set on them and they become no longer visible.

How do I go about implementing a tableViewHeader on a UITableView that snaps to a closed and open state but also respsects the group headings?

It seems as if the "open and closed" state are confusing people. The two states refer to the contentInset of the tableView content being set to the height of the tableViewHeader and then not.